# Search text from list in a table row and extracting it in new column if finding one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a list of titles where there are esports teams names. I need to extract them in a separate column. It would be easy if titles had same 'mask' but they are different.

I am wondering if there is a way to extract team name from title if I have a list of all teams. Like make a code to loop through each row and duplicate team name in new column if it finds one.

**Team List:**

```
teams = ['IG.V', 'Matador', 'Galaxy Racer', 'MG.Trust', 'Five brothers', 'Team Rocket', 'Cobra Gaming', 'Revenge Gaming', 'Secret', 'Virtus.pro']
```

**Expected result**

| N | Title | team1 | team2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [RU] IG.V 0:1 Matador (BO2) MS Mid-Autumn @Skor @fourApril | Ig.V | Matador |
| 2 | [RU] Galaxy Racer 0:0 MG.Trust (BO3) Moon Studio Carnival Cup @Mantis | Galaxy Racer | MG.Trust |
| 3 | [RU/EN] Five brothers - Team Rockets Asian Gold Occupation S19 | Five Brothers | Team Rocket |
| 4 | [RU/EN] Cobra Gaming - Revenge Gaming Masters Tournament S13 | Cobra Gaming | Revenge gaming |
| 5 | LF พากย์ Secret⚔️Virtus.pro (Bo3)EPIC League: Division 1 - รอบแบ่งกลุ่ม | Secret | Virtus.pro |

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with escaped values of lsit by `re.escape`, added word bondaries by `\b\b` and last add to original by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) :

```
import re
#change Team Rocket to Team Rockets for match
teams = ['IG.V', 'Matador', 'Galaxy Racer', 'MG.Trust', 
         'Five brothers', 'Team Rockets', 'Cobra Gaming', 
         'Revenge Gaming', 'Secret', 'Virtus.pro']


pat = "(" + '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in teams) + ")"

df = df.join(df['Title'].str.extractall(pat)[0].unstack().add_prefix('team'))

print (df)
   N                                              Title          team0  \
0  1  [RU] IG.V 0:1 Matador (BO2) MS Mid-Autumn @Sko...           IG.V   
1  2  [RU] Galaxy Racer 0:0 MG.Trust (BO3) Moon Stud...   Galaxy Racer   
2  3  [RU/EN] Five brothers - Team Rockets Asian Gol...  Five brothers   
3  4  [RU/EN] Cobra Gaming - Revenge Gaming Masters ...   Cobra Gaming   
4  5  LF พากย์ Secret⚔️Virtus.pro (Bo3)EPIC League:...        Secret   

            team1  
0         Matador  
1        MG.Trust  
2    Team Rockets  
3  Revenge Gaming  
4      Virtus.pro
```

EDIT: After some test solution is convert values to strings by `.astype(str)`:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('vcxvcvx.xlsx')
# print (df1)

df2 = pd.read_csv('testcase.csv', index_col=[0])
# print (df2)


pat = "(" + '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in df1['Teams'].astype(str)) + ")"

df = df2.join(df2['title'].str.extractall(pat)[0].unstack().add_prefix('team'))

# print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer!

When i am trying to process real data i got an error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 277, in escape
    pattern = str(pattern, 'latin1')
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, int found

I preprocessed this column before applying search of teams. There are no special characters or nums.

Comment: I think there is a problem because of non-latin characters in strings, because i cleared all of them from nums and spec.chars. Maybe i need to delete all non-lating characters and then appling your solution?

Comment: @NekitKravchenko - I think it is good idea.

Comment: @jezreal - Still same problem. Maybe We could talk somewhere else, where i can send You a file?

Comment: @NekitKravchenko - Is possible send me file to my email? Email is in my profile, only run python code